# IE class :active with image not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having a issue in internet explorer. Chrome and Firefox works.

The problem is when I have a button :hover effect works in IE even if I hover the button and image, but if I click (:active) in the image  doesn't work. Same happens if is a text or div.

Any turn around?

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7mwHe/1/), just try to click in the facebook icon, it should change to red on IE but seems like no click, only works if I click in yellow zone.

Comment: see here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-active

Comment: :active only works in IE with <a> tags that have an href attribute.

Comment: i have that problem too. i can't work around that but I suggest you to research about the :parent selector, e.g. (doesn't work on me): `a.btn > .img:active ~ span:parent {color:#000;}` The parent selector can only be used once in a selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/7mwHe/4/

I have made the icon into a (base64-encoded) background image (and resized down from 512x512px to 20x20px!)

Tested on Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera.

Comment: Thanks for that solution, not really solves. Because if I have another background image(beside the red color background and the moment) will be replaced with the facebook image.

Comment: @uınbɐɥs Ricardo Rodrigues is talking about <img> tag. Sometimes it cannot be replaced by background image easily, e.g. `<a>Enter <img src"logo.png"/> Now!</a>`